# audio not working on virtual machine

Tags: audio, virtual-machine, alsa, audio-recording, rhel-6

I am implementing a virtual agent using java. My agent works fine on my local machine. But when i deploy to Virtual machine agent is not able to speak due to lack of audio mixers on virtual machine. Virtual machine is hosted on Cloud.

Now my question is, Is it possible to install audio library on my red hat Linux virtual machine?

i Installed Alsa driver but still no audio.

Comment: What cloud are your VMs hosted in? If the VM is lacking audio end-points then that is your problem, and it's a probably you probably need to address with your host.

Comment: it is Saas. How do i add virtual audio card?

Comment: That isn't an answer. Who owns the computers that are hosting the cloud your VM is running in? What brand name or company? SaaS is the title of a type of service, not the name of a company I'm familiar with.

Comment: i am not sure about the name of company. How do i find it out?

Comment: In your question you state "Virtual machine is hosted on Cloud". What is "Cloud"?

Comment: its VMware Cloud.

Comment: There is likely no audio device installed on your virtual device then. And it would seem you're not very familiar with working in a virtualized environment. You probably need to go into the your management tools and actually add a virtual audio device to the VM, and THEN you'll be able to install an audio driver and have audio endpoints. I would also suggest reading a lot of the documentation for the system you're using to become more familiar with it and how it works, especially how it differs from a physical host.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that an audio device has not been added to the virtual machine.

In the management tools provided by your cloud provider you will need to make sure there is virtual audio hardware connected to the VM, THEN you'll be able to install drivers and then use those audio end-points.